# Full frame-rate across multiple OpenGL windows?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, sdl-2

I'm trying to make an OpenGL program with as many windows as I want. I know it's possible. I don't care if I have to use something other than SDL2, but I've tried GLFW3 and get the same results.

The problem is not that I can't create multiple windows or can't render to both of them. I can. The problem is no matter how I try to do it, whether I use a single thread or multiple, the frame rate is locked to a divisor of my monitor's refresh rate. What I mean is, if I have two windows rendering on the main thread and updated using SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window) I get 72fps for both of them (My monitor has a refresh rate of 144hz and 144/2=72hz). This is expected for a single thread because of v-sync. Each call to SDL_GL_SwapWindow is syncing the window to the refresh rate and 1/144 + 1/144 is 1/72. That's not the problem. The problem is I have tried using separate threads for each window and even then it runs at 72fps even though they should be rendering/swapping the buffers at the same time.

Example 1:

In this example, I have both windows rendering and swapping buffers on the main thread. This does what you would expect on a monitor with a refresh rate of 144hz. They render at 72fps.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#undef main

#include <glad/glad.h>

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window* w1 = SDL_CreateWindow("w1", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_Window* w2 = SDL_CreateWindow("w2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 700, 700, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    SDL_GLContext c1 = SDL_GL_CreateContext(w1);
    SDL_GLContext c2 = SDL_GL_CreateContext(w2);

    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(w1, c1);
    gladLoadGL();

    int r = 0, b = 0;

    bool running = true;
    while (running) {
        uint64_t startTime = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();

        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
            } else if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT) {
                if (event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE) {
                    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(c2);
                    SDL_DestroyWindow(w2);
                }
            }
        }

        SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(w1, c1);
        glClearColor(r / 255.0f, 0, 0, 1);
        r = (r + 1) % 256;
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(w1);

        SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(w2, c2);
        glClearColor(0, 0, b / 255.0f, 1);
        b = (b + 1) % 256;
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(w2);

        double deltaTime = (SDL_GetPerformanceCounter() - startTime) / (double)SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency();
        std::cout << 1.0 / deltaTime << " fps" << std::endl;
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(c1);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(w1);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Example 2:

In this example, I have both windows rendering and swapping buffers on their own threads. This doesn't do what I expect because it behaves the exact same as having them both on the same thread like in example 1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#undef main

#include <glad/glad.h>

void RenderThread(bool& running, SDL_Window* window) {
    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, context);
    gladLoadGL();

    int r = 0;
    while (running) {
        uint64_t startTime = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();

        glClearColor(r / 255.0f, 0, 0, 1);
        r = (r + 1) % 256;
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

        double deltaTime = (SDL_GetPerformanceCounter() - startTime) / (double)SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency();
        std::cout << 1.0 / deltaTime << " fps" << std::endl;
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
}

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window* w1 = SDL_CreateWindow("w1", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_Window* w2 = SDL_CreateWindow("w2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 700, 700, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    bool running = true, r1 = true, r2 = true;
    std::thread t1(RenderThread, std::ref(r1), w1);
    std::thread t2(RenderThread, std::ref(r2), w2);

    while (running) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
                r1 = false;
                t1.join();
            } else if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT) {
                if (event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE) {
                    r2 = false;
                    t2.join();
                    SDL_DestroyWindow(w2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(w1);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm fine with using another library for the windows. If my problem can be fixed with a different library please tell me which one.

Comment: Can't repro on this Kubuntu 20.04 box using that first program, getting a solid 60 fps.  2x 60hz monitors on a Vega 56, both windows are on the same monitor.

Comment: Perhaps it's a hard limit somewhere in the library stack. How does one window run?

Comment: @Anonymous1847 One window runs at 144hz/fps.

Comment: @genpfault Do you have two monitors? Could that be causing the difference even if they are both on the same monitor?

Comment: Yup, two monitors.  Disabling one of them still gives me 60 fps.

Comment: @genpfault Have you altered the code in any way?

Comment: @genpfault Example 1 with both windows 72fps https://ibb.co/Fkvp541 and 144fps with one window https://ibb.co/CbK9xn6.

Comment: [Just enough to get it to build](https://pastebin.com/D88MGPrr).

Comment: @genpfault The only thing I can think of is that your os vsyncs per program and not per window.

Comment: @NoahGav what's your OS and GPU/driver version? I suppose it really is up to graphics driver, locking with mutex on multiple contexts is not unheard of. My first thought is that "very good" driver could detect multiple contexts in a single thread, but that could be very tricky, and ok-ish driver should do fine with two threads. Just for fun, what happens if you add `SDL_Delay(5)` at the end of single thread loop?

Comment: @keltar I'm using Windows 10. My GPU is an RTX 2080 and my GPU driver is up-to-date (it is Geforce Game Ready Driver Version: 456.71).

Comment: @keltar When I added SDL_Delay(5) at the end of the single thread loop it still runs at 72fps with two windows and 144fps with one window. If I do SDL_Delay(13) (1000 / 72 is about 14ms) it runs at 72fps with two windows and 72fps with one window.

Comment: @NoahGav interesting. Just tested it on multiple systems and results are inconsistent at best. I have no problems on linux with amd (surprising - didn't expect driver to handle multicontext on single thread so well), but on windows only multithreaded version gets top fps (60 in my case). On nvidia with windows (not 2080 though, 1650s) I get max fps for both cases - no idea why multithreaded version don't work for your case. As for delay - no, it is "just for fun", but delay have to be smaller; with delay of 8 I got ~42fps on amd/windows when it was 30 w/o delay.

Comment: There is nothing fancy with delay at all, I was just trying to push queued frames a bit further apart so driver don't have to lock on next swap. Succeeded to some extent, but not enough. I don't expect it to be usable way to render things.